# Confluence not showing tips on wiki markup

Tags: confluence

After an upgrade, our confluence installation doesnt show the "Help Tips" on wiki markup (a box on the right side of the edit pane which give basic informations on wiki markup). If I view the source, I see that the div is there, but with a display:none attribute. This lead me to think that there is an option somewhere to activate or deactivate this, but I cant find it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Could it be that you are in rich text mode (slider "Rich Text")? There the Help Tips are hidden, because you normally use the rich text only. When you toggle then to "Wiki Markup", the Help Tips show up again.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find an option to show it again, and I can't but we are not using the default theme and it is visible
Try adding custom css to show it seems to have an id of helpcontent so you could do that. 
Although this will affect other views if not precisely targeted

If it is a route you want to persue !